# Can I install a copy of Magento Enterprise Cloud Edition in local server

Tags: magento-2.1, cloud, magento-2.1-ece

I am working on a project where the client has taken subscription of **Magento Enterprise Cloud Edition**.

I know that Magento Enterprise Cloud Edition enables us to use the following three types of environments, i.e. integration, staging, and production.

I want to a clone of production environment in my machine. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Any solution got for this ?

Answer (score 1):

To cover the question in details. I'll break them into multiple sections.

**1. Clone the environment to your local**

This is not possible that I've known of, you are expected to set up your own local development environment.

More information regarding the software version on Magento Cloud can be found here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/cloud/project/project-conf-files_magento-app.html

**2. Clone the code/application to your local**

Magento Cloud has a Git endpoint so you would be able to do a Git clone to your local. Make sure you run `composer install` to install relevant packages.

**3. Clone the database to your local**

Since only Magento Cloud server has access to the database and there is no write permission on the server itself to produce a database dump on the server - you would need to channel your MySQL connection via SSH connection to do a database dump. The information for your database connection should be in `app/etc/env.php`

More information on how do a database dump via SSH tunnel can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2989724/how-to-mysqldump-remote-db-from-local-machine

**4. Clone the media to your local**

Since it lives on Magento Cloud which you should have SSH access to. It would be as simple as do a `scp` to copy the directory back to your local environment. An example would be

`scp -r ssh_username@magento_cloud:/app/pub/media /your/local/path`

Please note on production environment it could be

`scp -r ssh_username@magento_cloud:/app/{your_unique_id}/pub/media /your/local/path`